# How to merge the folders : downloads - téléchargements / pictures - images / videos - vidéos?

Tags: unity

I had previously installed Ubuntu Unity 13.04 in French, and got the folders: téléchargements - images - vidéos

Then I reinstalled it in English and got the new folders: downloads - pictures - videos

A dialog box asked me to merge them but I refused it. Looks like now I changed my mind.

Indeed I would like to properly merge them together in order to have only French version of them and make Unity works fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see again that dialog box then:

1. Go in **System Settings** > **Usser Account**, select your user name and change the language in french.
2. Logout and login back.
3. After login you will be asked if you want to keep your personal folders in english or to change their names in french.
4. If you choose to change their names in french your folders will merge.

Another way  to merge them can be from command line. See this post: [Unix: How to merge two directories](https://superuser.com/questions/242638/unix-how-to-merge-two-directories).

For example if you run in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
cp -R ~/Images/* ~/Pictures
```

then the folder *Images* will merge into *Pictures*.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ~